# Why is this HTML code typed in URL bar as 'data:text/html' not working?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have this html code (below), which works perfectly as a hosted file (meaning the code is working) -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Read Text File</title>
    <!--<script src="https://thunkable.github.io/webviewer-extension/thunkableWebviewerExtension.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script>
    var ThunkableWebviewerExtension = (function () {
      const postMessageToWebview = (message) => {
        if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {
          window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(message);
        } else {
          window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
        }
      };
    
      const getReceiveMessageCallback = (fxn, hasReturnValue) => (event) => {
        if (typeof fxn === 'function') {
          if (event.data) {
            let dataObject;
            try {
              dataObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
            } catch (e) {
              // message is not valid json
            }
            if (dataObject && dataObject.type === 'ThunkablePostMessage' && hasReturnValue) {
              fxn(dataObject.message, (returnValue) => {
                const returnMessageObject = { type: 'ThunkablePostMessageReturnValue', uuid: dataObject.uuid, returnValue };
                postMessageToWebview(JSON.stringify(returnMessageObject));
              });
            } else if (!hasReturnValue && (!dataObject || dataObject.type !== 'ThunkablePostMessage')) {
              fxn(event.data);
            }
          }
        }
      };
    
      return {
        postMessage: postMessageToWebview,
        receiveMessage: function(fxn) {
          const callbackFunction = getReceiveMessageCallback(fxn, false);
          document.addEventListener('message', callbackFunction, false);
          window.addEventListener('message', callbackFunction, false);
        },
        receiveMessageWithReturnValue: function(fxn) {
          const callbackFunction = getReceiveMessageCallback(fxn, true);
          document.addEventListener('message', callbackFunction, false);
          window.addEventListener('message', callbackFunction, false);
        },
      };
    })();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
    <br>

    <pre id="output"></pre>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('inputfile')
            .addEventListener('change', function() {
            
            var fr=new FileReader();
            fr.onload=function(){
                //document.getElementById('output').textContent=fr.result;
                var msg = fr.result;
                ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage(msg);
            }
            fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is, turn this whole code into a long URL, and I found that by using `'data:text/html,<meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>'` at the start, then adding the code.

So the HTML url would become something like - `'data:text/html,<meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/><!DOCTYPE html><html><head> ...'`

I can see the file upload button, and even can select and upload a file. But, the script parts are not working - I am unable to catch the error here

Kindly guide/advice me here... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting a little bit, I think the problem might be that you haven't url-encoded it. Try using [this](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=URL_Encode(false)Find_/_Replace(%7B%27option%27:%27Regex%27,%27string%27:%27%5E%27%7D,%27data:text/html,%27,true,false,false,false)&input=PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw%2BCjxodG1sPgo8aGVhZD4KICAgIDx0aXRsZT5SZWFkIFRleHQgRmlsZTwvdGl0bGU%2BCiAgICA8IS0tPHNjcmlwdCBzcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vdGh1bmthYmxlLmdpdGh1Yi5pby93ZWJ2aWV3ZXItZXh0ZW5zaW9uL3RodW5rYWJsZVdlYnZpZXdlckV4dGVuc2lvbi5qcyIgdHlwZT0idGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0Ij48L3NjcmlwdD4tLT4KICAgIDxzY3JpcHQ%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%2BCgo8Ym9keT4KICAgIDxpbnB1dCB0eXBlPSJmaWxlIiBuYW1lPSJpbnB1dGZpbGUiIGlkPSJpbnB1dGZpbGUiPgogICAgPGJyPgoKICAgIDxwcmUgaWQ9Im91dHB1dCI%2BPC9wcmU%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%2BCjwvaHRtbD4K) instead of just pasting in the whole thing directly

(or copy it from here)

```
data:text/html,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ERead%20Text%20File%3C/title%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C!--%3Cscript%20src=%22https://thunkable.github.io/webviewer-extension/thunkableWebviewerExtension.js%22%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3E%3C/script%3E--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%3E%0A%20%20%20%20var%20ThunkableWebviewerExtension%20=%20(function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20postMessageToWebview%20=%20(message)%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(window.ReactNativeWebView)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(message);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window.parent.postMessage(message,%20'*');%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20getReceiveMessageCallback%20=%20(fxn,%20hasReturnValue)%20=%3E%20(event)%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20fxn%20===%20'function')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(event.data)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20dataObject;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20try%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dataObject%20=%20JSON.parse(event.data);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20catch%20(e)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20message%20is%20not%20valid%20json%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(dataObject%20&&%20dataObject.type%20===%20'ThunkablePostMessage'%20&&%20hasReturnValue)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fxn(dataObject.message,%20(returnValue)%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20returnMessageObject%20=%20%7B%20type:%20'ThunkablePostMessageReturnValue',%20uuid:%20dataObject.uuid,%20returnValue%20%7D;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20postMessageToWebview(JSON.stringify(returnMessageObject));%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(!hasReturnValue%20&&%20(!dataObject%20%7C%7C%20dataObject.type%20!==%20'ThunkablePostMessage'))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fxn(event.data);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20postMessage:%20postMessageToWebview,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20receiveMessage:%20function(fxn)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20callbackFunction%20=%20getReceiveMessageCallback(fxn,%20false);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.addEventListener('message',%20callbackFunction,%20false);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window.addEventListener('message',%20callbackFunction,%20false);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20receiveMessageWithReturnValue:%20function(fxn)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20callbackFunction%20=%20getReceiveMessageCallback(fxn,%20true);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.addEventListener('message',%20callbackFunction,%20false);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window.addEventListener('message',%20callbackFunction,%20false);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)();%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/script%3E%0A%3C/head%3E%0A%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type=%22file%22%20name=%22inputfile%22%20id=%22inputfile%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cpre%20id=%22output%22%3E%3C/pre%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.getElementById('inputfile')%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.addEventListener('change',%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20fr=new%20FileReader();%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fr.onload=function()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//document.getElementById('output').textContent=fr.result;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20msg%20=%20fr.result;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage(msg);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fr.readAsText(this.files%5B0%5D);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/script%3E%0A%3C/body%3E%0A%3C/html%3E%0A
```

But I could be wrong -- I'm not very experienced with javascript